# Bootstrap 3: breaking a two-column row into two one-column rows when on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I currently have:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4" id="LocationWrapper">
                <div class="FullWidth HorizontallyCentered">Select the location:</div>
                <select id="ddlLocation"></select>
                <span id="LocationNote">blablabla</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8" id="GraphsOptionsWrapper">
                <div class="FullWidth HorizontallyCentered">Select the graph:</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This works fine for desktop. However, on mobile the columns are just too small to hold what is needed. In this case, it would be better to have two rows (instead of two columns in one row), with one column in each row.

How could I do it without duplicating the content? The content has some controls like select that should be unique on the page.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this structure will help you.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4" id="LocationWrapper">
            <div class="FullWidth HorizontallyCentered">Select the location:</div>
            <select id="ddlLocation"></select>
            <span id="LocationNote">blablabla</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8" id="GraphsOptionsWrapper">
            <div class="FullWidth HorizontallyCentered">Select the graph:</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I missed the fact that col-xs-* does not stack vertically. Only sm, md and lg does.